# Rails Model - Update Nested Key/Value in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql

I have a model with the following table format:

```
string  "name"
integer "line_id"
json    "filters"
```

Where the `filters` field contains a json object with nested keys. I want to modify a specific key without overwriting the rest of the json.

Currently, the json object stored in `filters` looks like

```
{
  "ext": {"name": "filter", "id": 3},
  "int": {"name": "numb", "id": 1}
}
```

I'm trying to update `int.name`'s value to `"remove"` without modifying the rest of the json object.

If I do the following, it'll simply overwrite the entire json object instead of modifying that specific key:

```
Model.where("filters->>'int'->>'name' IS NOT NULL").update(
  filters: {
    int: {
      name: "remove"
    }
  }
)
```

How can I simply update that one key with the path `int.name` while keeping the rest of the attributes the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

which version of rails are you using?   if you are using rails 5, you should be able to

```
m = Model.where("filters->>'int'->>'name' IS NOT NULL").first
m.filters['name'] = 'remove'
m.save
```

this will leave the existing hash keys in place.

I think with rails 4, you need a json serializer on the field, but should work the same way once you have the serializer, i believe.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing after all and it works well! I was hoping there'd be an API for it but doesn't look like so afterall

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
models = Model.where("filters->>'int'->>'name' IS NOT NULL")
  .each_with_object({}) do |m,obj|
    # credit to mudasobwa for the tap usage 
    obj[m.id] = {filters: m.filters.tap { |h| h['int']['name'] = 'remove' } }
  end 
Model.update(models.keys,models.values)
```

I have never used a `json` column so I am unsure if the anticipated value is meant to be JSON or a `Hash` that will be converted to JSON before insertion but the update statement will be akin to

```
Model.update([1],[{
         "ext"=> {"name"=> "filter", "id"=> 3},
         "int"=> {"name"=> "remove", "id"=> 1}
       }])
```

This uses [`ActiveRecord::Relation#update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update) where the first `Array` is the ids to update and the second `Array` is the new values to associate with those ids.